# How to create GPO for put cleanmgr on users desktop?

Tags: group-policy

I already create some shortcut on desktop user from gpo but i dont understand how to create a shortcut for running cleanmgr from users desktop. 
Like that they can run this one when they want to.

Thank you all

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this TechNet article](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753580(v=ws.11).aspx) for how to use Group Policy to create a shortcut item

You can use the path `%SystemRoot%\System32\cleanmgr.exe` as the shortcut target.